# Can't set cookie with play framework

Tags: playframework, setcookie

I am new to play framework (1.2.4) and i am getting a hard time working around setting cookies. I've read through the 1.2.4 api doc but can't find what am doing wrong. The cookie doesn't get set but instead the applications does a GET request with the cookie values like this: `index?name=user&value=123&duration=1d` and the page goes blank. `render()` doesn't get called. Am I lacking a setting in the application.conf? Below is my code.

```
public static void setCookie(String name, String value, String duration) {
    // Setting cookie
    System.out.println(">> Setting Cookie :" + name);
    response.setCookie(name, Crypto.sign(value), duration);
}

public static Http.Cookie getCookie(String key) {
    // retrieving cookie by key
    return Http.Response.current().cookies.get(key);
}
```

This is where I call setCookie

```
public static void index() {
    // some code.
    setCookie("user", "123", "1d");
    render();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because when you call `setCookie` Play thinks you are calling a different action (because you setCookie method is in a controller, and is `public static void`.

You can either make the method private, or mark the setCookie method with the `@Util` annotation.